# Counting unique id's based on condition(s) - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that contains a bunch of unique ids and would like to get a value count of how many of these ids contain both "original" and "copy" in the content column. Also, how would I do this across multiple columns?

I know how to do this in excel but fairly new to python, so any help would be super useful!

df:

```
user_id  content_type  status
1234     original      pending
1234     copy          blocked
4321     original      blocked
4321     original      distributed
5678     original      blocked
5678     copy          pending
```

Output:

original + copy = 2

original + pending = 1

original + blocked = 2

etc..

Comment: should original + pending = 2 and not 1?

Comment: @chris in referencing the df above, there's only a single row with both original as the content type and pending as status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Groups having 'copy':

```
sum(df.groupby('user_id').apply(lambda x: 'copy' in x['content_type'].unique()))
```

(summation of rows having 'copy'; True=1 and False=0)

Or

```
df.groupby('user_id').apply(lambda x: x[x['content_type']=='copy']).shape[0]
```

Count by `status`:

```
df[df['content_type'] == 'original'].groupby('status').size()

status
blocked        2
distributed    1
pending        1
```

Or if you want to count both original and copy,

```
df.groupby(['content_type','status']).size()

content_type  status     
copy          blocked        1
              pending        1
original      blocked        2
              distributed    1
              pending        1
dtype: int64
```